# Wind Waker: Barrier Skip 101

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

What are the flags that trigger the cs for the breaking of Ganon's barrier? I've looked, but to no avail, even the speedrunning community www.speedrunslive.com doesn't know. Please help. Then it will change the speedrun Dramatically and I can get WR. Thanks in advance! Also, if there is a way to get the source code for the barrier, that would be useful too. perhaps some sort of working decompiler from .iso to .cpp or .c : Thanks again!(in advance)

Comment: [Barrier skip is not possible. Period.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdMGw7IUsj4)

Comment: As a sidenote, we also don't provide source code for games.  *Especially* in a format to be used in an emulator, or for decompiling.  That's well outside our scope.

Answer (score 5):

As of December 1st 2013 there is no known way of skipping the barrier. [This page](http://zeldaspeedruns.com/tww/Miscellaneous/barrier-skip) explains that in addition to the damaging part of the barrier, there's an invisible wall inside it. Both the knockback zone and the invisible wall are infinitely high and infinitely low, so you can't zombie hover over it or under it, and there's no edges to grab onto to clip through. The page doesn't say what flags control when the barrier breaks, though I strongly suspect it would be "has True Master Sword" (it's just common sense), so no skipping the Earth or Wind Temples.

Comment: That didn't help. Sorry, but because of that very answer is why i even asked in the first place! I want to know what the flags are for the cs! one of them is True Master Sword, another is the fight in the MS chamber, also the triforce of courage, but i don't know the others. THAT is what i know. What I want to know are the other flags so that I know for sure how to trigger the cutscene.

Comment: Not to be rude, but how does knowing how to trigger the cutscene help you if you still can't skip the parts that activate the flags?

Comment: Well, if you know the flags that trigger the cutscene, getting them early and then going to hyrule 2,in theory the barrier would be broken. The cs would start the moment you went to the barrier and hit it with your sword.